# Suggest CSS classes based on array of classes in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, intellisense

In 90% of my work I use the same CSS classes from the same library. Is there a way to make VSCode suggest those classes?

I used CSS IntelliSense, but it drains my processing power.

Answer (score 0):

You can [create a snippet](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets) for each class name.

Or you can write a very simple extension that returns that list of class as intellisense suggestions. [Here's](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/tree/master/completions-sample) an example completion provider